# allow user to submit an edit/update request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site for a hobby im working on that has restaurant reviews on it.  I want users to be able to add new restaurants in as well as edit the info on other restaurants which they may or may have not added to the site.  I am not sure what the best way to approach this is.  I have a few options I have thought of, but I'm not sure.

Only allow restaurants that are on say google places

- main concern with this approach is if a restaurant a user wants to go to isn't listed on google places then what

Allow users to manually add in restaurants and check google places and fill in pertinent info like address phone if not on google places then let user add all info in manually... if is or is'nt on google places still have to manually accept restaurant to the site

- the main downside of this is I may have to spend tons of time making sure a restaurant is real or isn't real

Anyone have any ideas?

also i am running rails should i just use a versioning gem to achieve the request an update so that way i can moderate updates or new restaurants...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no Ruby guy, so I will not comment on that part.  But depending on the size of your user base I would solve it by user moderation or do it manually. If you haven't got that many users moderating the new entries should be feasible and if you got many users it should be possible to accept any new entry and then allow users to flag bad entries like it is done here on SO or on foursquare or Facebook Places.

Of course you could choose to accept anything available on Google Places, but only allowing entries that can be found there would make it annoying for users to enter new info which would discourage them from doing so.

Comment: yeh i guess you are correct.. and it will be a brand new site so really i could do all the moderation... i just would like to have it in place so it basically can moderate itself while i add new features